# How to overwrite images via FTP upload in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ftp, upload, storage

I have a third party Laravel project with a function to upload images.
The function generates an operator folder, category sub-folder and product sub-sub-folder with a product image within.

There is no resize option here, so many files are 4MB or more.
I wrote a simple bash script to resize the images and tried to upload them via FTP: now all the files are around 100Kb on the server but in browser inspector I still have 4MB image.

I tried ***artisan clear:clear*** and ***view:clear***.
No results.
I even tried to delete one or more images and to rename the entire category folder but browsers are still capable to visualize large images with the same old url.  (???)

Cache were cleared on the client side.
The main folder is ***public/storage/image/***
The filesystem.php in config folder says:

`return[
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
    'public' => [

    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public'
    ],

]`

How can laravel show images when I rename/delete folders and images or (better) what am I missing?

Comment: Is there any CDN somewhere that is caching the pictures? CloudFlare maybe? If you access the image directly do you see the same behavior? does `php artisan optimize:clear` help?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can't see any CDN service here and I suppose the url in the browser inspector should be the external one.
I haven't "optimize" command, I cleared view cache and config

Something strange: if I check the "response" in the inspector I can see a 0 x 0 empty image but all browsers can show the image, even with cache/cookie cleared, even in private mode! I'm going crazy...Could it be any symlink stuff? If it is i should find the 4MB file somewhere (but I can't!)